# How to decide which subclass method to override the superclass? java

Tags: java, inheritance, polymorphism

I am building a classical project and it's time to implement an AI player in this game. Therefore, my idea is to create a class called `NimAIPlayer`, and another class called `NimHumanPlayer`. Both of them inherit the abstract class `NimPlayer`.

The AI player is playing automatically that I define an abstract method in `NimPlayer` called `moveStone()`. And I define the different methods for both `NimHumanPlayer` and `NimAIPlayer` class to override.

If the player is human, then, the input is from the user; on the other hand, if the player is AI, then it automatically generates a random integer in certain rules.

What I've tried is, but it's not working:

```
if (player1 instanceof NimHumanPlayer) {
      player1.moveStone();
   } else {
      player1.moveStone();
```

Any help is appreciated! I've watched a lot of tutorials and it seems there is such a way to choose which subclass I want to override.

Here is part of my `NimPlayer` class:

```
import java.io.Serializable;
abstract class NimPlayer extends Nimsys implements Serializable  {

private String userName;
private String familyName;
private String givenName;
private int gamesPlayed;
private int gamesWon;

public NimPlayer(String userName, String familyName, String givenName) {

    this.userName = userName;
    this.familyName = familyName;
    this.givenName = givenName;
    this.gamesPlayed = 0;
    this.gamesWon = 0;
}

public abstract int moveStone();
}
//getters and setters
}
```

Part of my `NimHumanPlayer`:

```
public class NimHumanPlayer extends NimPlayer{

public NimHumanPlayer(String userName, String familyName, String givenName) {
    super(userName, familyName, givenName);

}

public int moveStone() {
    int stoneTaken = in.nextInt(); // in is the scanner inherited from super class
    return stoneTaken;
}


}
```

Part of my `NimAIPlayer`:

```
public class NimAIPlayer extends NimPlayer {
private NimGame nimGame = new NimGame(); // create a obj to call the field

public NimAIPlayer(String userName, String familyName, String givenName) {
    super(userName, familyName, givenName);

}

public int moveStone(int upperBound, int stoneBalance) {

    stoneBalance = nimGame.stoneBalance; // for calculation
    upperBound = nimGame.upperBound; // for calculation

    int stoneTaken = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(1, upperBound +1 ); 
    if (stoneTaken > stoneBalance) {
        stoneTaken =  ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(1, stoneBalance +1 );
    }

    return stoneTaken;
}
```

Part of the `NimGame` field for references:

```
public class NimGame extends Nimsys {

NimPlayer player1;
NimPlayer player2;

String initialStoneInput;
String dataRemoval;

int stars;
int stoneBalance;
int initialStone;
int upperBound;

public NimGame() {
}

public NimGame(NimModel nimModel, String initialStoneInput, String dataRemoval, NimPlayer player1, NimPlayer player2) {
    this.initialStoneInput = initialStoneInput;
    this.dataRemoval = dataRemoval;
    this.player1 = player1;
    this.player2 = player2;
}
```

Comment: You are calling `moveStone()` on `player1` in both if and else clauses.

Comment: I need to call both `moveStone` because it is using the abstract method.  @Omid.N

Comment: Aren't the two players two  separate objects?

Comment: yes, but I want to distinguish `moveStone()` between a human and the AI.

Comment: I am quiet confused with your code. I don't understand why you want to know which type it is. When you call moveStone() on the players objects the overridden methods in subclasses will be called and since you are using Scanner in NimHumanPlayer you will be able to put input.

Comment: My idea is to distinguish which type of player is in the game. If the AI is in, it will input the stone randomly. So, there are four possibilities {AI, human}, {AI, AI}, {human, AI}, {human, hman}.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213785/discussion-between-omid-n-and-woden).